# Cron Job User Permissions

Tags: cron, cron-job

Is it possible to run a cli.php without user and password if cron owner has sufficient privileges? Having added it my Joomla dashboard is over run with entries for the cron user logging in. The user I created I didn't give any special acl but it seems to work. I'm assuming due to my cron rights. Suggestions?
Thanks
Wallace

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear exactly what issue you're wanting to address here, but you might want to look at running 'cv' from cron instead of cli.php/cron.php.  That does not require a password and will not record as a login.

See https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/jobs/#cv